# Perform procedural function on varchar field

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql

I have a dataset merged from two databases, one American (imperial units) and one European (metric units). I have cleaned up the records duplicated between the two data sets, and converted the data to be in inches, but the single database feeds both a United States web store and a European web store.

The European web store needs to display units in CM, not inches. This is not a problem for most of the fields, as the measurements are stored as integers and can be converted in a view. I want to convert the instances of inch based measurements in the text fields to centimeters, but the only custom functions I've ever seen for SQL are set based functions, not the traditional procedure based operation I need which would involve looping through the text field.

### Current

```
table productData
id    |  height  |  width  |  detail  
00001 |      12  |     18  |  Up to 12" of steel
00002 |      24  |     18  |  Up to 24" of steel
00003 |       8  |      8  |  Brace with multiple 2" x 3" brackets
...   |      ..  |     ..  |  ...

view productData_EU
SELECT 
    id, 
    CEILING(height * 5 / 2) height,
    CEILING(width * 5 / 2) width,
    detail
FROM productData

id    |  height  |  width  |  detail  
00001 |      30  |     45  |  Up to 12" of steel
00002 |      60  |     45  |  Up to 24" of steel
00003 |      20  |     20  |  Brace with multiple 2" x 3" brackets
...   |      ..  |     ..  |  ...
```

### Desired

```
view productData_EU
SELECT 
    id, 
    CEILING(height * 5 / 2) height,
    CEILING(width * 5 / 2) width,
    CUSTOMFUNCTION(detail) detail
FROM productData

id    |  height  |  width  |  detail  
00001 |      30  |     45  |  Up to 30 cm of steel
00002 |      60  |     45  |  Up to 60 cm of steel
00003 |      20  |     20  |  Brace with multiple 5 cm x 8 cm brackets
...   |      ..  |     ..  |  ...
```

How do I perform a traditional function (`CUSTOMFUNCTION`) on each record when making this view? I have the option of a scalar UDF which nests a lot of `CHARINDEX()` and `REPLACE()`, but a loop would be far more flexible.

Comment: might it be easier to do it in the UI layer? Really the DB should not be concerned with a presentational detail like this - the data clearly is text and not used for calculations, so it's up to the UI to internationalise the content.

Comment: I personally would like to do it at the interface level. Unfortunately, I am not involved on that end, and currently cannot make a push for it.

Comment: Personally I woudl store both sets of data in separate columns since this is text data as  Detail and Detail_CM. That way you only have to convert once rather than with every query as this is going to be a major problem to convert as far as performance and you certainly under no circumstances want to ro this row by row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified my EXTRACT Table-Valued Function to perform a global search and replace and conversion to CM.  Assuming this is the only conversion required.

Now, I didn't like converting a TVF to a scalar, but the performance should still be respectable.

This will convert any value begining with a space and ending with a double-quote.  For example Some value 12" of steel

This can be further parametrized but I didn't want to over-engineer it

**Example**

```
Declare @productData table (id varchar(25),height int,width int ,detail varchar(100))
Insert Into @productData values
('00001', 12, 18,'Up to 12" of steel'),
('00002', 24, 18,'Up to 24" of steel'),
('00003',  8,  8,'Brace with multiple 2" x 3" brackets')

Select id
      ,height = ceiling(height * 5 / 2.0)
      ,width  = ceiling(width * 5 / 2.0)
      ,detail = [dbo].[CUSTOMFUNCTION1](A.detail)
 From  @productData A
```

**Returns**

[image]

**The UDF**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CUSTOMFUNCTION1](@String varchar(max))
Returns varchar(max) as  
Begin 
    with   cte1(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select null)) From master..spt_values N1,master..spt_values N2 ),
           cte2(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(' ') From cte1 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(' ')) = ' '),
           cte3(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(' ',@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte2 S)

    Select @String = Replace(@String,' '+RetVal+'"',concat(' ',ceiling(RetVal * 5 / 2.0),' cm'))
    From (
            Select RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex('"',RetVal)-1) 
             From  (Select *,RetVal = Substring(@String, N, L) From cte3) A
             Where charindex('"',RetVal)>1
         ) R1

    Return @String

End
```

Comment: One Note: if your string won't exceed 2,500 you can remove    >>>>  ,master..spt_values N2  <<<

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant. I'm still trying to follow some of the steps, but it's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Fritz Happy it helped.  Just ping me if you have questions  :)

Comment: @Fritz Just make sure you are using the version lised above.  I made a couple of small edits to ensure proper replacements

Comment: Ok, I'll be sure to do that.

Comment: Only issue I had was that I forgot that `PROD` is on SQL Server 2005 SP3, which was causing me issues with `concat()`. A simple switch to `' ' + cast(ceiling(RetVal * 5 / 2.0) as varchar) + ' cm'` fixed it up for me. Thanks again!

Comment: @Fritz Well done.  2005 ?  Time to let that one retire